# Menu item color change

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a website: sites.northwestern.edu/mrsec

I noticed when I click on Education menu item, both Education and Facilities menu items turn gray instead of just Education. Does anyone know what is causing this glitch? I can't figure out why it's being like this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: need to add some code..

Comment: Something linked with sub menus - check classes current-page-ancestor current-page-parent

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is server side, facilities menu has class `current-page-parent` and the following css rules applies on it :

```
.menu-menu-1-container li.current-page-parent a {
    background: none!important;
    background-color: #BBB8B8!important;
}
```

> (index):1395